# How to send real time data with mqtt, nodejs and socket.io to flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io, mqtt

I want to send data from mqtt broker (hivemq.com) using socket.io, nodejs and mqtt to flutter.

This is my method to subscribe to a topic and store data to firebase realtime database, now how can i use socket.io to send data to flutter?

```
//inserting data from mqtt into firebase realtime database
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
const port = process.argv.slice(2)[0];
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const mqtt = require('mqtt')
const client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://broker.hivemq.com')
var firebase = require('firebase');
const server = http.Server(app)
const socketIo = require('socket.io')(server)

function mqtt_messsageReceived(topic, message, packet) {
    if(message){
      let messageObject = JSON.parse(message)
      insertMessage(topic, messageObject, packet)
      socketIo.emit('geocoordinateData', messageObject);

    }
}
socketIo.on('connection', (socket) =>{
  console.log(' ${socket.id}')
  socket.emit('request', 'ok');
 
})
```

```
//calling function to mqtt client event
client.on('message', mqtt_messsageReceived)
```

in client side i initialize socke.io like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;
void main() {
 IO.Socket socket = IO.io('https://xxxx.herokuapp.com/');
print('mainohhhhh');
 socket.onConnect((data) {
    print('connect');
    socket.emit('msg', 'test');
    print('socketohhhhh');
  });
socket.on('geocoordinateData', (data) => print(data));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

when I run, nothing happens at the client level

How can i wrap socket.io function to send data to flutter?

Comment: what have you tried and how didn't it work?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68617442/edit) question, do not try to add code as comments

Comment: to find a solution to my problem, I followed what was given as a solution to this address  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203090/messages-not-received-using-node-js-mqtt-client-with-socket-io] in server side. also the version of socket.io of my server is different from the client, so I put the same version on the client and server side and it worked